# SQLDataReader Null to datetime

Tags: c#

Having an issue with casting a datetime from a reader where the value is null.

```
form._date101 = reader[52] == DBNull.Value ? DBNull.Value : (DateTime?)reader[52];
```

getting: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'System.DateTime?'

any ideas?

Comment: You could probably discombobulate yourself if you broke that into two lines.

Comment: The two expressions which can be returned must be the same type. Your first possibility is returning a DBNull type, and the next is returning a DateTime? type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I *suspect* you meant:

```
form._date101 = reader[52] == DBNull.Value ? null : (DateTime?)reader[52];
```

That's assuming that `_date101` is a field of type `DateTime?`. I expect you want to say "Use the null value of `DateTime?` if the value was null in the database; otherwise use the non-null value.

Answer (score 2):

You can also take Jon's answer and add it as an extension method like this:

```cs
public static class ReaderExtensions
{
    public static DateTime? GetNullableDateTime(this SqlDataReader reader, string name) =>
        reader[name] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : (DateTime?)reader[name];
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```cs
item.PatientDob = reader.GetNullableDateTime("Birth_Dt");
```